# Integral diverges but method works?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Based on this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4454826/595084

I want to find the integral $$I_1=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sin(x)}{e^x+1}\text{ d}x$$
In the method the answer uses, it converts this integral into $$I(n)=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\sinh(nx)}{e^x+1}\text{ d}x$$ and solves for $-iI(i)$. In other words, it converted the integral into $$I_2=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{-i\sinh(ix)}{e^x+1}\text{ d}x$$
In the process of finding $I(n)$, we perform the substitutions detailed in the aforementioned answer and arrive at two integrals, namely $$A=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{x^{-n}}{x+1}\text{ d}x$$ $$B=\int^{\infty}_1x^{-n-1}\text{ d}x$$
Solving these integrals however give us some restrictions. For instance, when we solve for $B$, the upper bound forces us to place the restriction that $\Re(n)>0$ due to the fact that $\frac{1}{\infty^{bi}}$ is undefined for any constant $b$ for $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Not only that, to solve for $A$, I set up a branch cut (since $n$ is not an integer, it can be classified as a root, and thus through testing $0$ is a branch point. We can set up starting from there in any direction) along the positive real axis and used a keyhole contour (I think I could have used a rectangular contour, but that requires 5 integrals while the keyhole has 4, so I picked the latter).

In the process of solving the integral for the outer part of the keyhole contour, I was forced to place the restriction that $0<\Re(n)<1$ to have it vanish.

In the end, the result for $I(n)$ was $$\frac{\pi}{2}\csc(\pi n)−\frac{1}{2n}$$
Plugging in $n=i$ and multiplying by $-i$ does indeed give us the correct answer. However, this is not supposed to happen.

Clearly, $\Re(i)=0$, which violates the fact that $\Re(n)>0$. As a matter of fact, if we place the substitution $n=i$ in prematurely, say into $B$, the integral even fails to converge! The upper bound basically means that we rotate around the origin an infinite amount of times. I don't even think the integral converges in a Lebesgue sense, much less Riemann.

So why is it that despite clearly violating the restrictions that exist, plugging in $n=i$ for $I(n)$ works for calculating $I_1$?

Comment: You have many situations where the hypothesis of a theorem are not satisfied, while the conclusion of the theorem still holds in a particular case.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net why will the conclusion hold when the criteria are not met? It does not make sense other than if it were a coincidence

Comment: Since $|\sinh nx|\sim\frac12\exp|x\Re n|$ for large $x\Re n\in\Bbb C$, $I(n)$ converges provided $|\Re n|<1$. Someone will hopefully flesh out that observation into a proof the desired case follows by analytic continuation.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty t^{-i}/(t + 1) dt$ and $\int_1^\infty t^{-1 - i} dt$ diverge both as improper Riemann integrals and as Lebesgue integrals, but the derivation is correct for $0 < \operatorname {Re} a < 1$. The integral $I(a)$ and $(\pi \csc \pi a - 1/a)/2$ (defined to take value $0$ at $a = 0$) are analytic on $-1 < \operatorname {Re} a < 1$. Now apply the identity theorem.

Comment: @Maxim would you mind elaborating on that? Both integrals diverge but you say that it is somehow defined to be 0 at $a=0$ and exist on the interval $-1$ to $1$? I don't quite follow.

Comment: @Maxim also why is $\frac{\pi}{2}\csc(\pi a)-\frac{1}{2a}$ defined to be 0 at a=0?

Comment: If you the know the result $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh\left((a+ib)x \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \csc \left(\pi(a+ib) \right) - \frac{1}{2(a+ib)}$$ holds for $0 < a < 1$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, then what you need to argue is that $$\lim_{a \to 0^{+}}  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh\left((a+ib)x \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh\left(ibx \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx. $$

Comment: @RandomVariable Wait oh that is actually an interesting method. I'll try to see if i can get anything out of it. Meanwhile is it possible for you to write an answer with that if youre able to prove it as well? >.>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, if you know that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh\left((a+ib)x \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \csc \left(\pi(a+ib) \right) - \frac{1}{2(a+ib)}$$ for $0 < a< 1$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, then what you need to show is that $$\lim_{a \to 0^{+}}  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh\left((a+ib)x \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh\left(ibx \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx.$$

To show this, you can modify the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/122261).

Let $(a_{n})$ be a nonnegative sequence that converges to $0$, and assume that $  a_{n} <\delta <1$.

Since the magnitude of $\sinh(z)$ increases as $\Re(z)$ increases, $$f_{n}(x) = \left|\frac{\sinh\left((a_{n}+ib)x \right)}{e^{x}+1}  \right| $$ is dominated by $$g(x) = \frac{\left|\sinh\left((\delta+ib)x \right)\right|}{e^{x}+1},  $$ which is integrable on $(0, \infty)$ since $\delta <1$.

We can therefore use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that $$\begin{align} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}   \frac{\sinh\left((a_{n}+ib)x \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx  &=  \int_{0}^{\infty}  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sinh\left((a_{n}+ib)x \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\sinh\left(ibx \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx . \end{align}$$

Since this is true for all sequences $(a_{n})$ described above, the function $$F(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh\left((a+ib)x \right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx$$ has a right-hand limit at $a=0$, and it's equal to $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh\left(ibx\right)}{e^{x}+1} \, \mathrm dx. $$

Comment: Hmm just one more quick question, why the right handed limit in particular?

Comment: @Max0815 Since what is known is the value of the integral for positive values of $a$ less than $1$, we want to approach $a=0$ from the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fully understand the argument now! Have the bounty xd

Answer (score 2):

Manipulations with divergent integrals requires strict proof.
Let us consider alternative way.

Are known the presentations
$$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-kx}\sin x = \dfrac1{k^2+1},\qquad(k\ge 1)\tag1$$
$$\operatorname{csch} u=\dfrac1u+2u\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^2\pi^2+u^2}.\tag2$$
or
$$u\operatorname{csch} u-1=2u^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^2\pi^2+u^2}.$$

Then
$$I=\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{e^x+1}\text dx 
= \int\limits_0^\infty\dfrac {\sin x e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\text dx
= \int\limits_0^\infty\sin x e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}e^{-kx}\text dx
=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2+1},$$
$$I=\dfrac12(1-\pi\operatorname{csch} \pi).$$

Comment: Yes, that is one of the methods provided on the question I have cited at the top(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4454631/595084). However, this question is in regards to that one particular answer and why despite it seemingly diverge, the answer still coming out to be right. Your answer does not answer the question :(

Comment: @Max0815 Incorrect method can lead to right answer, I've tried to point that correct answers can be easy ones.